# Easier way to verify input is >0 in Python?

Tags: python, int, verification

I've written function enterReadings for the user to enter a number and I've got the following verification to ensure it's a positive integer. I'm thinking that there's a simpler way to write this but don't know where to start, any help is massively appreciated!

```
def enterReadings(message):
    while True:
        try:
            readingsCount = int(input(message))
            if readingsCount <= 0:
                print("Please enter a positive integer")
                continue
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a positive integer")
            readingsCount = 0
        if readingsCount > 0:  
            readingsCount += readingsCount
            return readingsCount
```

Comment: `if readingsCount > 0` to check for a +ve number should be good enough.

Comment: Your last `if` can be removed and the lines under it should replace the `break`. I don't think that `break` does what you mean anyway.

Comment: Do you really want to break from the loop and return (implicit) `None` if a positive integer was entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit shorter:

```
def enterReadings(message):
    while True:
        try:
            readingsCount = int(input(message))
            assert readingsCount > 0
            return readingsCount
        except:
            print("Please enter a positive integer")
```

BTW why do you double your `readingsCount`? Is that what you intended?

Comment: Ah amazing thank you. No the doubling of readingsCount is an error on my part!

Comment: Suggestion for the first line: `def enterReadings(message:str="Enter a positive number: ") -> int:`

Comment: In the original code `readingsCount` isn't doubled. The program never reaches that part of the code.

Comment: Sure, change `int` to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, `int` can also be negative, so you have to check it.

Python 3.8+:

```py
def enterReadings(message):
    while True:
        try:
            if (n := int(input(message))) > 0:
                return 2*n
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print("Please enter a positive integer")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is absolutely OK, you check if an input is a number (int) and is positive.

> Clear is better than clever.

Comment: It is not okay. Try to print out the returned result for a *correct* entry.